# How to pass an object for DB insert?

Tags: php, database, laravel, controller, insert

I need to insert the record into the db. How should i pass it throught controller?

For example to delete record i pass Id, and it looks like

routes.php func:

```
Route::get('/template/delete/{id}', array(
'as' => 'template_delete',
'uses' => 'ThoughtRiver\Template\Controllers\TemplateController@deleteTemplate'
));
```

controller func:

```
public function deleteTemplate($id)
    {
        return DB::table('template')->where('Id', '=', $id)->delete();
    }
```

So how to pass record object in the case of insert?
It's a backend functional, so object should be taken not from the form. (From the http
 post request body?)

Comment: You need `HTML form, route and function` that handles the data.

Comment: It's a backend func, no form should exist. So how should looks route func, how to translate post request body?

Comment: I have found this tutorial to help you how to create [restful api in Laravel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2B5EfMvExU])

Comment: @AmrAly very usefull tutorial! Thanks! It saved me.

Comment: glad to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you grab data from a form, so use Request object to get the data:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Model::create($request->all());
}
```

`$request->all()` will create an array with data from submitted form. To make `create()` method work, you should fill the [$fillable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment) array first.

Comment: i'm newbie in php, can you please show how should look route.php func, and where to fill fillable array? and my data shoud be taken not from the form, it a backend functional. How to pass object in this case? Post request route?

Comment: @Mira you should create and fill the `$fillable` array in the model (like `User`). Route should look like `Route::post('some-data/store', 'SomeController@store')`. I'd recommend you to watch some Laravel tutorial or read a book, so you'll avoid so many mistakes and save a lot of time.